# Сборка проекта Intellij Idea с базой данных

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, развертывание

Имеется проект hibernate + javafx. Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить базу данных(sqlite) в jar файл или, если я хочу отдельным файлом, то где прописать путь к ней?
Сейчас выдаёт ошибку: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: users)

Comment: Если есть выбор, то для Java лучше взять "родную" БД, например, H2. Нашёл такую ссылку: SQLite DB (только для чтения) в Jar архиве: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019974/how-to-include-sqlite-database-in-executable-jar . Но я бы всё равно не шёл таким путём. Базу лучше держать отдельно.

Comment: Ответ на вторую часть вопроса без уточнений дать не удастся. Непонятно как и что уже сделано. Может это с ходу поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788068/hibernate-make-database-only-if-not-exists а так же https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207826/hibernate-h2-database-relative-path